# angular access component method within service, no provider error

Tags: angular

I am getting a this error, so I am obviously missing something here

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ApiHandlerService -> ApiHandlerModalComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ApiHandlerService -> ApiHandlerModalComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ApiHandlerModalComponent!
```

I have a service that gets called on every API call that determines if the server returns an exception rather than the expected payload. I then have a modal component that needs to display if that case is true. So my service is this, in which I import the modal component in order to call the `showModal()` method and pass the payload into it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiHandlerModalComponent } from 'app/modules/ui/components/api-handler-modal/api-handler-modal.component';


@Injectable()
export class ApiHandlerService {

    exception: any = [];

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient,
        private apiHandler: ApiHandlerModalComponent
    ) {
    }

    responseHandler(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            const obj = {
                exception: false,
                payload: response.payload
            };
            return obj;
        } else {
            const obj = {
                exception: true,
                message: response.exception.message,
                segNum: response.exception.seqNum
            };
            this.apiHandler.showModal(obj);
            return obj;
        }
    }

    errorHandler(err) {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                this.router.navigate(['/app-login']);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

then in a shared module i have the modal component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-handler-modal',
  templateUrl: './api-handler-modal.component.html'
})
export class ApiHandlerModalComponent {

    @ViewChild('autoShownModal') autoShownModal: ModalDirective;

    isModalShown = false;

    constructor() { }

    showModal(obj?): void {
        this.isModalShown = true;
        console.log(obj);
    }

    hideModal(): void {
        this.autoShownModal.hide();
    }

    onHidden(): void {
        this.isModalShown = false;
    }

}
```

So according to the error I have not set a provider. I guess I am just a bit lost as to where and how to fix this?

app.module.ts:

```
/* import angular modules */
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { BreadcrumbsModule } from 'ng2-breadcrumbs';
import { UiModule } from 'app/modules/ui/ui.module';

/* import routers */
import { Routing } from './app.routing';

/* import authentication */
import { LoginService } from './modules/login/services/login.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/gaurds/auth.guard';
import { AdminGuard } from './auth/gaurds/admin.gaurd';

/* import components */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    }),
    BreadcrumbsModule,
    UiModule,
    Routing,
  ],
  providers: [
    LoginService,
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    AdminGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You're injecting the component into a service? why? Also from the look of your registrations, the component and service are missing.

Comment: You should never call component methods from your service. Make your service return a value and call `showModal()` from within the component itself.

Comment: @yurzui I added app-module to my OP

Comment: You are injecting `ApiHandlerModalComponent` like if it was a service in  `ApiHandlerService`. It's all the way around, service are injected in Componentes, not Components in services.

Comment: Your modal component should subscribe to an observable from the service that will determine when it should be visible.

Comment: @Hoyen this makes sense, I suppose I am still learning how Observables work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **ApiHandlerModalComponent** to the providers array, so your app.module.ts should be:

```
/* import angular modules */
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { BreadcrumbsModule } from 'ng2-breadcrumbs';
import { UiModule } from 'app/modules/ui/ui.module';

/* import routers */
import { Routing } from './app.routing';

/* import authentication */
import { LoginService } from './modules/login/services/login.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/gaurds/auth.guard';
import { AdminGuard } from './auth/gaurds/admin.gaurd';

/* import components */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    }),
    BreadcrumbsModule,
    UiModule,
    Routing,
  ],
  providers: [
    LoginService,
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    AdminGuard,
    ApiHandlerModalComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there better solution for your application is to use Subject(Behavior or Replay):

To do what you want you have to go the following steps:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiHandlerService {

    exception: any = [];
    heyShowModal = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);  <---add Subject

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient,
        //private apiHandler: ApiHandlerModalComponent <---remove it
    ) {
    }

    responseHandler(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            const obj = {
                exception: false,
                payload: response.payload
            };
            return obj;
        } else {
            const obj = {
                exception: true,
                message: response.exception.message,
                segNum: response.exception.seqNum
            };
            this.heyShowModal.next(obj);  <-- next method to call modal in component
            return obj;
        }
    }

    errorHandler(err) {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                this.router.navigate(['/app-login']);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

then in component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-handler-modal',
  templateUrl: './api-handler-modal.component.html'
})
export class ApiHandlerModalComponent, OnInit, OnDestroy {

@ViewChild('autoShownModal') autoShownModal: ModalDirective;

  isModalShown = false;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private apiHandlerService :ApiHandlerService) { } // <-- here you have to inject service

  ngOnInit() {  // <--here was my mistake
      this.subscription = this.apiHandlerService.heyShowModal.subscribe(
          obj => this.showModal(obj);
      )
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

  showModal(obj?): void {
    this.isModalShown = true;
    console.log(obj);
}

...
```

}

And put ApiHandlerService into providers, where you want to use it.

Comment: I really need to learn rxjs, I am missing something here as nothing is getting passe to the component. when I subscribe to heyShowModal and the console.log obj, nothing is output

Comment: Hi there. Could you please check couple things. 1.) Do you create provider for ApiHandlerService? 2.) Where do you call responseHandler method ? It should work or it should show some error in console.

Comment: Yes the ApiHandlerService exists in a shared module that I import into all my other modules. The response handler is called in all my components the use http.get/pull. I know this part is working otherwise I would not be getting the payload in the component template, which I am.

Comment: ou... f....ck )) My mistake sorry, I inject Service in component in wrong place ))) please check my component edit one more time... I inject Service in ngOnInit, but had to do it in constructor... now it has to work

Comment: And please check do you implement onInit and OnDestroy in your component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166383/discussion-between-nikolay-zatonatskiy-and-sandra-willford).